GEOS C++: Delete a coordinate in geos::geom::CoordinateSequence
In previous versions of libgeos we made use of the class geos::geom::CoordinateArraySequence. It had the following command:
void deleteAt(std::size_t pos); //Delete Coordinate at position pos (list will shrink)

Unfortunately in libgeos 3.13 there is only geos::geom::CoordinateSequence left. How can we achieve to delete a specific coordinate in this class?
It would be nice if you could provide a little code example. Thanks in advance!
